# How to keep both ionic 1, 3, version in my system

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Initaially i was working with ionic 1.7.6 version with many apps. And by today some how i have changed to version 3.0.0. Now when i open my old projects under `package.json` i see the version as 3.0.0 instead of `1.7.6`. And when i do `sudo ionic build android` it throws me some error to upgrade the version.

So now i have uninstall the ionic & cordova from my system.

Now i want to keep `ionic 1 version 1.7.6`  as well as `ionic 3 version 3.0.0` how can i do it now.

so when ever i open the ionic 1 project i need to work on angularjs with ionic 1 version.

And when ever i open the project that i have created with version 3 i need to work with latest version of angular is with ionic 3..

please some one expalain me what should i need to do ??

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have installed ionic globally. If you want to run the local/project version of ionic you need to `sudo ./node_modules/ionic/ionic ...`.
This will be the version of ionic as defined in the package.json of the project.

You can tuck this nicely away however using npm scripts (in your package.json):
e.g.

```
"scripts": {
    "ionic": "sudo ./node_modules/ionic/ionic build "
  }
```

Ten simply execute `npm run ionic -- android`

Comment: i haven't install any ionic version now globally...... i have ionic 1 version project and ionic 3 vesion project. now what should i need to first ... ionic 1 or ionic 3..  but when ever i install with version ionic 1.7.6 also it shows version : 3.0.0

Comment: okay, now in my mac when i enter `ionic version` it show `3.0.0` But i want to open new ionic 1 project too with angular js1.. then what should i need to do ??

Comment: if you can do ionic version from anywhere then this means that you did install ionic globally. Please try ./node_modules/ionic/ionic version in the ionic 1 & 3 projects.

Comment: okay, now when i see my ionic version it shows `3.0.0`. Now i want to create a new project in `ionic v1`. Now how can i create that with the beta version or how can i create a new ionic v1 project when i have `ionic cli 3.0.0`..